# Error code 13 while deploying google cloud function (terraform) from dev to qa

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, terraform-provider-gcp, google-container-registry, google-artifact-registry

I am facing an issue while deploying google cloud functions using terraform from dev to qa.

Here is an error code that I got in gitlab.

```
Error: Error waiting for Creating Cloud Functions Function: Error code 13, message: Build failed: Build error details not available
```

```
Error: Error waiting for Creating CloudFunctions Function: Error code 13, message: Build failed: Build error details not available.Please check the logs at https:<<link>>. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#build for in-depth troubleshooting documentation for build related errors.
```

This is observation: same cloud function is working in dev and I could see the CF is deployed with `Google Container Registry`.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QttV.png)

In QA also it is deployed with `Google Container Registry` under `Image repository` but it is not working in QA with same properties.

I tried to change manually container location as `Google managed Artifact Registry` and it worked.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r71me.png)

But I am not sure how to deal this in terraform because dev is working without `Google managed Artifact Registry` at the same time qa is not working without `Google managed Artifact Registry`.

Let me know how to fix the issue.

The expectation is the cloud function should work even if I deploy to QA.

Comment: Is there any possibility to face error 13 when google service account don't have sufficient privileges to use Google Container Registry?